# How to check Spring profile explicitly?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I would like to check that my application runs only under given set of allowed profiles.

I would write

```
@Autowire
Environment environment;

@PostConstruct
public void checkAndReportProfiles() {

    // checks
    ... environment.getActiveProfiles()
```

but the problem is that this runs after all beans were attempted to initialize and failed if profiles were incorrect.

I want to check profiles explicitly and fail with explicit message.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: you could register an `EnvironmentPostProcessor` and validate profiles there: `org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor=<YourPostProcessor>`. The method that will be called has the definition of `@Override
 public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) { .. }` so you have access to `Environment` to check for profiles. Would that be an option?

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**: you can create a bean which performes the checks for you.

```java
@Component
public class TestBean {
    public TestBean() {
        throw new BeanInitializationException("error message");
    }
}
```

to execute this before certain problematic beans you can annotate theese beans with `@DependsOn`

But now you have a bean with no purpose hanging around.

**Option 2**:
Perform the checks in a configration class.

To get access to the spring evironment or configuration properties, you can inject them via constructor.

```java
@Configuration
public class TestConfiguration {
    public TestConfiguration(Environment environment, @Value("${some.key}") String property) {
        String[] profiles = environment.getActiveProfiles();

        // perform tests here
        throw new BeanInitializationException("error message");
    }
}
```

**Option 3**: Create beans programatically and check before the bean is created.

```java
@Configuration
public class TestConfiguration {
    @Value("${some.key}") 
    String property;
    
    private final Environment environment;
    
    public TestConfiguration(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Bean
    public SomeBean someBean() {
        if(whateverToTest) {
            throw new BeanInitializationException("error message");
        }
        return new SomeBean();
    }
}
```

**Option 4**: Perform test in the constructor of that particular bean. The constructor is called first.

```java
@Component
public class SomeBean {
    public SomeBean() {
        if(whateverToTest) {
            throw new BeanInitializationException("error message");
        }
    }
}
```

---

Option 3 is the cleanest solution in my opinion, but also the most difficult to implement. Especially if you are using constructor based injections.

Comment: Can you elaborate option #2 please? Where do you get information about profiles?

Comment: i updated option 2

Answer (score -1):

To explicitly check the Spring profile, you can use the following approach:

1)Set the active profile via the --spring.profiles.active application launch option:`java -jar myapp.jar --spring.profiles.active=production`

2)Set the active profile via the environment:
`export SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=productionjava -jar myapp.jar`

3)Set the active profile via an application.properties or application.yml file:
`# application.properties spring.profiles.active=production`

`# application.yml spring: profiles:  active: production`

Comment: this is how you set the profile. but you cannot perform checks against the configuration.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this.

Create a class for keeping the association profile/error

```java
public enum ErrorProfile {
   default("This is the error num 1"),
   dev("This is the error num 2"),
   test("This is the error num 3"),
   prod("This is the error num 4");

   private String profile;
   private String message;
   ErrorProfile(String profile, String message){
      this.profile = profile;
      this.profile = message;
   }
}
```

Then create a profile checker that execute at the lunch of your spring project during the context loading.

Java provides a valueOf(String) method for all enum types.
Thus, we can always get an enum value based on the declared name. This means that, after we get the value of the profile we can retrieve the message code with:

```java
ErrorProfile.valueOf("prod")
```

Then it will be enough to print it in the Logs, Exception or whatever you need.

```java
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class PropertiesLogger {
    @Value("${spring.profiles.active}")
    private String activeProfile;

    @PostConstruct
    public void printProperties() {
        log.debug("Loading application-context profiles. Active profile found: {} [message: {}]",
                activeProfile,
                ErrorProfile.valueOf(activeProfile));

        // and in this case (cause you want to rise an exception with that message)
        throw new RuntimeException(ErrorProfile.valueOf(activeProfile))
    }
}
```

Comment: this approach introduces hard-to-see-at-first problems, namely due to the fact it's not `activeProfile`... it's `activeProfiles`. It's a comma-separated list, and it's quite common to have multiple profiles enabled at once (e.g. `test,ci` or `prod,beta` e.g.) - your code will not only fail in those cases, but also make the reader believe that e.g. `prod,beta` doesn't mean both `prod` and `beta`, where in fact it does. Proper way to handle it would be to split it on commas and iterate through the array, or use any more sophisticated algorithm (e.g. `@ActiveProfile` etc.)